# Libpng Installation error

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Libpng1.6.39 but it's giving me this error

```
make: *** [Makefile:2012: install] Error 2
```

I've looked around online and I can't seem to find any solutions for this particular error code. I did see something like it and tried `Make Clean` and then followed it with `Make VERBOSE-1` but that didn't work.

Comment: Where is the version of Ubuntu? Where is the commands you typed to get this error? Where is any details to be able to help you? Any help you get is as good as the info in the question. Your question has no details.

Comment: AFAIK `make` exits with status 2 if *any* error occurred. You will need to include a larger context around the error message to diagnose anything particular - the command to get verbose output in this context is likely `make VERBOSE=1` not `Make VERBOSE-1`